# CSS Transition for parent and child without delay

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```css
a {
  color: #F00;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

a:hover {
  color: #FF0;
}

a:hover i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

a i {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-plus">+</i>
  Button Text
</a>
```

I want that the transition effect changes the color and the space between the icon and the text at the exact same time, when hovering over the link.

This way it first changes the space and then changes the color, so the animation plays in "sequential" mode.

How am I able to get the animation correct, so it changes EXACTLY with the space and the color, and not with this delay.

Comment: I don't see any delay, both transitions happen at the exact same time for me.

Comment: Same here, both simultaneously...

Comment: I've updated the snippet to "simulate" the FontAwesome library - now you can see the delay :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the just the `margin` transition on the inner element:

```css
a {
  color: #F00;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

a:hover {
  color: #FF0;
}

a:hover i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

a i {
  transition: margin 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-plus">+</i>
  Button Text
</a>
```